# How to center and align stacked radio buttons

Tags: html, css, forms, radio-button, css-position

I am trying to have an input form with radio buttons where each option is stacked on top of each other and all of them are aligned (center) by the radio button, not by the length of its label.

End result I am looking for:
[image]

My best approach so far was to center everything, with `position: absolute`. Something like this.

```css
position: absolute;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
left: 0;
right: 0;
text-align: center
```

However, with this approach the options are influenced by the length of the text.
[image]

Removing the `text-align` above, it removes the centering altogether...

Comment: Please add your HTML code.

Answer (score 1):

Place the three radio buttons within a container that is within another container like so.

```
<body>
  <div class="center-horizonally">
    <div class="radio-btn-container">
      <div class="radio-1">yes</div>
      <div class="radio-2">no</div>
      <div class="radio-3">maybe</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<style>
  .center-horizonally{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }
</style>
```

The most outer container has `display: flex;` and `justify-content: center;` which will horizontally center the second container that has the buttons. The second container keeps the three radio buttons aligned vertically on the left. This is probably not the best way to do this but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to center elements is by using `display: flex;` on parent element and `margin: auto;` on child:

```css
.container
{
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}

.container .middle
{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="middle">
    <div>Do you enjoy pizza with pineapple</div>
    <div class="middle">
      <div><label><input type="radio" name="blah">Yay</label></div>
      <div><label><input type="radio" name="blah">Nay</label></div>
      <div><label><input type="radio" name="blah">Never heard of it</label></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```